# NF in an awk function

Tags: awk

I have a file in which i have mobile numbers and their categories. Not all the mobile number are having category available.for example

```
mobile123456678
category1
mobile345968483
category2
mobile956868483
mobile958688504
mobile958688438
mobile058684838
category4
mobile238348459
category5
mobile958584939
category6
```

etc.etc

so i have used below awk command and it gave the the mobile numbers for which category is available. but i am not able to understand how it worked

```
cat file | awk '{if ($0~/mobile/) {k=$NF;l=($NF-1)} else {print k,$0}}'
```

.

```
mobile123456678 category1
mobile345968483 category2
mobile058684838 category4
```

etc

pls let me know how this worked.

Comment: Why is `l` set when it is never used ?

Comment: Never use a variable named `l` as it looks far too much like the number `1`. Every line of your input has 1 field so NF is always 1 so idk what you are trying to do in  that script.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to print those lines whose next line is not on the form `mobileXXX`, you can directly say:

```
$ awk '/^mobile/ {m=$NF; next} {print m, $0}' file
mobile123456678 category1
mobile345968483 category2
mobile058684838 category4
mobile238348459 category5
mobile958584939 category6
```

This checks if a line starts with the text `mobile` and, if so, stores in a variable `m` the mobile value (last field `$NF`*, as per your input and code, although it could also be `$0` in this case). Then, it moves to the next record.

If the line did not start with `mobile`, it prints the previously stored mobile together with the current line.

What I just suggested is  a more idiomatic way to write what you had:

```
awk '{if ($0~/mobile/) {k=$NF;l=($NF-1)} else {print k,$0}}' file
```

Because the `if () {action} else {else_action}` can be avoided by saying `condition {action; next} {else_action}`.

---

<sub>*</sub> `$NF` refers to the last field in a given record, since `NF` stands for number of fields and `$n` for the n-th field.